# Probability of picking balls from 3 boxes without replacement

Tags: probability, markov-chains

This problem has been come just from curiosity. Simple combinatorial arguments seem really complicated.

I have 3 boxes each having 75 green (G) balls, 20 red (R) balls & 5 blue (B) balls.
Each time I will take 1 ball from each boxes without replacement.
Thus boxes get lighter and lighter each time. I will do this process 100 times.
I will get success if each time drawn balls are RBG or GGG or GGR or its permutation. Thus order does not matter. Hence GBR or BGR etc. are also fine. Note that we have total 100 trials. If in any trial drawn balls are different say GRR etc., we will not get success.    At some time it must be GGG.  I want to find the success probability. Any good approximation is also fine. I thought about Central Limit Theorem without getting any idea. I thought from the direction of Markov chains also. But I do not get any idea. Please help me.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Do you do this $100$ times without replacing the balls?  So that the boxes get lighter and lighter each time?  And what does *success* mean?  Do you mean that you get one of those three ordered triples at least once? (of course, it's clear that you must get $GGG$ at least once if you don't replace).   Or are you asking for the distribution of the number of successes?  Something else?

Comment: Yes boxes get lighter and lighter each time. Success means each time we need one of the three options. We have total 100 times. Yes, some time it must be GGG. I want to find probability of success.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain this...I don't think it is at all clear.  For example, does the order matter?  You write $RGB$...would $GBR$ be a fail?

Comment: Please check now. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I think it's clear now.  You could get an exact answer recursively, but there are lots of states to keep track of so the computation will be ugly.  You may be better off simulating it.

Comment: As a quick way to move forward, note that you need every Blue draw to come along with a Green and a Red.  As there are $15$ blues in total, that's a tough requirement.  Shouldn't be too hard to get the probability that this fails, which would be fairly informatiive.

Comment: Will you kindly give some idea for recursive relations.

Comment: The problem is that you need to keep track of all the possible contents of the three boxes.  Thus, drawing $GGG$ first moves you to a similar state where you are starting with $74$ greens in each box (and  no change to the reds or blues).  And you need to look at all the possible states that flow from every possible single draw success.  Lots and lots of states, as I said.

Comment: That said, a direct assault might be doable.  As I suggested, start by requiring that each $B$ come with $GR$.  Once that condition is met, now note that each $R$ must come with $GG$.  Tedious, to be sure, but maybe not that terrible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129166/discussion-between-user12290-and-lulu).